# Cypress e2e testing: How to access new tab by clicking on "href". I don't have target attribute to remove and test on new opened tab?

Tags: tabs, cypress

[This attached image is my HTML code for href which will open a new tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVnCd.jpg)

The DOM has iframe so I wrote below code accessed the href and it will open in new tab. I am unable to access the newly opened tab, though I know the method that would have target attribute so we remove that and open in same tab but here I don't have any target attributes.

Please check this and help to access my new tab.

```
cy.visit('https://yopmail.com/en/')
cy.get('.ycptinput').type('some_name {enter}')
cy.wait(2000)
cy.get('#ifmail').its('0.contentDocument.body').then(cy.wrap).find('a').click()
```

Comment: Have you tried to extract the href from the `<a>` tag and visit it?

Comment: Yes I did, used cy.visit() then showed me to use cy.origin() since this is another domain. After using cy.origin() it showing me the error "cy.origin() requires the last argument to be a function. You passed: ` ` . I am not sure how to solve this.

Comment: Have you read the documentation on using `cy.origin()`? https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/origin

Comment: Kindly note this, Everybody would have read the documentation and gone through other sources to find a solution. We post a question here to get the suggestions and clear answers. If you can help, take me to write a correct script. @DJSDev

Comment: Apologies if it came off as rude, but your previous comment quite literally asked how to solve a usage problem, which would be remedied by reading the documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cy.origin()` command is meant to solve the "new tab" problem.

It's a bit new, so expect some teething problems. Basically, it sets up a sand-boxed domain that can use Cypress commands.

Anything from outside `cy.origin()` that you want to use inside (for example, the link you found) needs special handling to pass in.

It gets passed in on a special `args` option, and is received in the same pattern.

```js
let link;

cy.visit('https://yopmail.com/en/')
cy.get('.ycptinput').type('some_name {enter}')
cy.wait(2000)
cy.get('#ifmail').its('0.contentDocument.body')
  .then($body => {
    link = $body.find('a')[0].href
  })

cy.then(() => {          // this just waits for above block to complete

  const newOrigin = link.split('?')[0]  // remove query params 
      .replace('http://', 'https://')   // correct for secure protocol

  cy.origin(newOrigin, { args: { link } }, ({ link }) => {

    cy.visit(link)       // same as ".find('a').click()" but works cross-domain
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I have already tried this kind of solution and also I tried yours but I am getting an error as "cy.origin() requires the first argument to be either a url (https://www.example.com/path) or a domain name (example.com). Query parameters are not allowed." I am not sure this is because of href or something.

Comment: What does `link` contain? It should be a string when you use `link = $body.find('a')[0].href`

Comment: Reading the message a bit more carefully, I think the link needs to be split at the `?` character. I will change the code to do that.

Comment: Your solution seems working but I think problem is with url="http://url6287.wholesoftmarket.com/ls/click?upn=-2Fb58LO4QsdgvwfwNo3TX-2FJ1pyc-2FY8J1TFUqLL2k48mHZ0HK8Jko78fSWfdugy293AtAkRThRwqMu0Xyd9wS5Udj5S31MNGAbYlQw3NtgR0Q-3D0Opo_Fmyjk-2FjVnGSK5ZdUISbmGcj9UKWrx-2B-2BioyzIPGN1SYpR1gbZ-2BGD9IXpgZCw9o712cMISESf5SbP01Hj9rhmbrB2fPacV-2Bmg4xJb-2B-2B-2FUZ7DbITsHJJLlT-2F1kKxz7w6730jCruxPDzHV4mC2vPz8gmN65CLmvDprzwoOyFVQRZJA7NEDH8Kp3-2BW4mXk03C5clQvWGwxV36v6OXYLn3m0cUr3-2FyfxFuujGnq5xioW1P4Ik-3D". It keeps telling me that "You may only cy.visit() same-origin URLs within cy.origin()".

Comment: It's working when I hardcode the url inside cy.origin('https://dev.wholesoftmarket.com/memberReg/62cfb2a5f35aff002c8a4773', args, ()=>{}) but not by using newOrigin variable. It throwing an error The previous URL you visited was: 'http://wholesoftmarket.com' and You're attempting to visit this URL: 'https://dev.wholesoftmarket.com'

Comment: Yeah I tried it out on my own link - it's not enough just to `.split('?')`, some links are lazy about the protocol (gives `http://` but browser corrects to secure `https://`). Can happen in older page that was originally written without `https://`. Now-days chrome auto-corrects, so problem is never caught. But `cy.origin()` is in beta still, no doubt they will eventually auto-correct that as well. I added extra code above to handle it.

Comment: Wow that's great! It's working clearly and you explained the way of solution beautifully, Thank you so much.

Comment: Your'e welcome, thanks for your own help in getting the solution.