# Cypress click on link in mailhog body email

Tags: cypress, domparser, mailhog

I need a help about testing mailhog with cypress.

I am trying to click on "Forgot password" link in email body, any advice how to do it?

Comment: Please share the HTML of your app.

Answer (score 2):

The method proposed by @VincentLarue is more complicated than needed, and has some bugs.

Check out this [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/a4ZXso/1).

```html
<a href="mydomain/verify/fXxo4s_isP-mlm">Verify account</a>
```

```js
const regex = /(\/verify\/.*)"/    

const url= content.match(regex)[1]
cy.visit(url)
```

But it is actually a fragile method, the better way is to parse the response body.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the body string to get the link, but it would be messy.

Better to use a `DOMParser`

```js
cy.mhGetAllMails().mhFirst().mhGetBody().then(body => {

  const parser = new DOMParser();
  const doc = parser.parseFromString(body, 'text/html')  // make a DOM 

  const anchor = doc.querySelector('a')                  // look for anchor tag
  const href = anchor.href                               // get the link

  cy.visit(href)                                         // visit the link
})
```

**Notes**

You can't click on the link directly with `.click()` since the DOM created above is not the live one attached to Cypress. But you should be able to `cy.visit(href)` which does the same thing.

The only problem I foresee is a `cross-origin` error - if you get that, use the `cy.origin()` command [Ref](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/origin).

---

Please see @Mr.PrasadJ question [How to access new tab by clicking on "href"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72994758/cypress-e2e-testing-how-to-access-new-tab-by-clicking-on-href-i-dont-have-t) if you need more details on `cy.origin()` usage with email body.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an HTML-based web app, you can directly use the text to find and click the element.

```js
cy.contains('Forgot password').click()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
But the thing is that i am getting email body (with type of its says its a string) but can be MIME, not sure.
This is how i am getting all emails and checking if subject is "Reset password, then i wanted to parse body to get link.
But split is not working for me, i tried to match it by regex as well, not sure if mail hog have some way to copy link than to visit it in Cypress.
I hope i make it a bit more clear:
    cy.mhGetAllMails().mhFirst().mhGetBody().should('contain', 'Hello')
    cy.mhGetAllMails().mhFirst().mhGetBody().then(body => {
    })

Comment: Can you do this and share whats getting logged `cy.mhGetAllMails().mhFirst().mhGetBody().then(body => {cy.log(body)})`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, parsing the body didn't work (I could not query my "a" tag). I used a regex to retrieve my link and then click it.

In the mail body, my link looked like :

```html
<a href="mydomain/verify/fXxo4s_isP-mlm">Verify account</a>
```

But in the log of

```js
cy.mhGetAllMails().mhFirst().mhGetBody().then(body => {cy.log(body)})
```

it was melted with randoms `=` and `\r\n` since it was not parsed...

Working solution for me was to extract that match with a pattern accepting those character then remove them. And finally rebuild the link to visit it:

```js
cy.mhGetAllMails().mhFirst().mhGetBody().then(content => {
        let token = content.match('verify\/([A-Za-z0-9=~_\\r\\n-]+)<')[1];
        token = token.replace(/(\r\n|=)/gm, "");
        cy.visit('/verify/' + token);
    })
```

Maybe not the cleaner solution but I hope it can helps