# Capture a variable in a stubbed function

Tags: cypress

I have a test case which opens a secondary window. From what I read online, you should prevent this second window opening and visit the url that should have been opened. However, in all the test example I saw, the second url is static. In my case, I need it to be dynamic. This is why I'm using a cy.stub() to a window opening and trying to get the url from it.

```js
cy.visit('https://myUrl.com');

cy.window().then(win => {
  cy.stub(win, 'open', newUrl => {
    cy.wrap(newUrl).as('newUrl');
  });
});

cy.get('#myButton').click(); // opens new window at new url with generated keys

cy.get('@newUrl').then(newUrl => {
  cy.visit(newUrl);
});
```

However, the cy.wrap() inside the cy.stub() triggers this error:

```js
Error:        CypressError: Cypress detected that you returned a promise from a command while also invoking one or more cy commands in that promise.

The command that returned the promise was:

  > `cy.click()`

The cy command you invoked inside the promise was:

  > `cy.wrap()`

Because Cypress commands are already promise-like, you don't need to wrap them or return your own promise.
```

Basically my question is how to capture the url in a stub for later use. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is using `cy.wrap()` or any `cy` commands inside an event listener. The code you have is valid, and the error should actually be a warning IMO.

One way to handle it is with a plain JS variable.

You may also need a `cy.origin()` wrapper for this test.

In a recent similar question [How to access new tab by clicking on "href"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73008241/16997707) it was found that the `cy.visit(newUrl)` was causing a reload of the test window, which looses all the data (variables and aliases) previously obtained.

```js
cy.visit('https://myUrl.com');

let nextUrl;

cy.window().then(win => {
  cy.stub(win, 'open', newUrl => {
    nextUrl = newUrl
  });
});

cy.get('#myButton').click(); // opens new window at new url with generated keys

cy.then(() => {

  const newOrigin = nextUrl.split('?')[0]  // remove query params 
      .replace('http://', 'https://')      // correct for secure protocol

  cy.origin(newOrigin, { args: { nextUrl } }, ({ nextUrl }) => {
    cy.visit(nextUrl) 
  })
})
```

---

**Alternative way to alias**

Looking again at your code, you may be able to apply the alias this way

```js
cy.window().then(win => {
  cy.stub(win, 'open').as('newUrl');
})

cy.get('#myButton').click(); 

cy.get('@newUrl').then(newUrl => {
  cy.visit(newUrl);
})
```

Comment: I didn't realize you could simply use a cy.then() to resolve Cypress's promise-like statements. I'm sure this will solve a lot of my problems. The first solution works great. Thanks a lot!

I tried the second solution and what gets stored in newUrl is 'open'. First solution works great though! Thanks again!